# Regex in Python for TR

Tags: python, regex, web

I wanted to scrap a website, specifically contents in the TR tags under tbody:

> http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/products/#sortField=oi&sortAsc=false&venues=3&page=1&cleared=1&group=1

```
under <tbody> tag
```

there are many

```
<tr class = "- bandingon">
<tr class = "- bandingoff">
[...] tags
```

I wanted to get information which is stored ***in each*** table row (***tr*** class)

For that I will have write some regex definition for the tr class:

```
findrows = re.compile('<tr class="-bandingon">(.*)</tr>')
findrows = re.compile('<tr class="-bandingoff">(.*)</tr>')
```

Is there a way to combine the 2 together into one regex?

Comment: `banding(on|off)` would do the job, also I would use ungreedy matching `(.*?)`.

Comment: could you explain what the "?" mark will do?

Comment: Take a look at these 2 examples: [greedy](http://regex101.com/r/jI3fB8), [non greedy](http://regex101.com/r/kD1uW3) and you'll understand soon what the benefits are by using `?`. Also take a look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) and check "Laziness Instead of Greediness" for an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a regex. Use an [HTML parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for row in soup.select('tr.bandingon, tr.bandingoff'):
    print row.get_text()
```

It's cleaner, easier to work with and is more robust than regex.

Also, before resorting to scraping, look for APIs. That site has a JSON API, which is much easier to use:

```
http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/ProductSlate/V1/List/500/1?sortField=oi&sortAsc=false&venues=3&page=1&cleared=1&group=1&r=NDGWCTX4
```

Comment: Do I have to define row before?

Comment: @Josh: You're probably using Python 3. In Python 3, `print` is a function, so you have to call it like `print(row.get_text())`.

Comment: I don't get an output after I run this, is there something wrong with how I'm search for info?

Comment: @Josh: The website loads those elements with AJAX, so they won't be there when you load the page.

Comment: So there isn't a way to capture those elements?

Comment: @Josh: There is. Just use the JSON feed for the page. That's what the webpage is loading with JavaScript and turning into HTML elements.

Comment: Could you give an example please, I'm not sure how to use that.

Comment: @Josh: That's what research is for. I'm not going to spoonfeed you.

Answer (score 2):

Use a non-capturing match group. There are other issues with what you've posted, in that you have to handle differences in spaces, but just editing your original regex, you just need to use `(?:` to indicate a non-capturing group.

```
findrows = re.compile('<tr class="-(?:bandingon|bandingoff)">(.*)</tr>')
```

If you want to get closer to actually managing everything, you probably want to allow for extra spaces (like those in your examples), like this:

```
findrows = re.compile('<tr\s+class\s*=\s*[\'"]-\s*(?:bandingon|bandingoff)[\'"]\s*>(.*)</tr>')
```

Ultimately, you might want to go with something like BeautifulSoup instead--way more flexible and with less edge cases.

Comment: The actual expression is this: <tr class="- bandingOn"> (and bandingOff), so how would you properly manage this?

Comment: Well then you only have one space, so you don't need all the `\s`. You could use the first form and just add a space after the dash. Aside from that, you should read up on regular expressions if you are still having issues.